# two trisurf plots on the same graph with different colors

Tags: matlab

I have two [trisurfs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/trisurf.html) on the same graph. I would like to have one red and one blue, but I can't seem to get the two plots to have different colors using colormap. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
figure
[x,y]=meshgrid(1:15,1:15);
tri = delaunay(x,y);
z1 = peaks(15);
th1 = trisurf(tri,x,y,z1);
set(th1, 'FaceColor', 'b')

hold all
z2 = 0.4*peaks(15);
th2 = trisurf(tri,x,y,z2);
set(th2, 'FaceColor', 'r')
hold off
```